# Is it possible to pass comparison operators as parameters into functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Is there a way to specify the function in the `if` condition in the arguments to a function? For example, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
a = int(input('number between 0 and 5'))
b = >=
def fun1(a, b):
    if a b 0:
        print('...')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use methods from the `operator` library if you want to use the comparision operator as a parameter to a function -- in this case, you're looking for [`operator.ge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.ge):

```py
import operator
a = int(input('number between 0 and 5'))
b = operator.ge

def fun1(a, b):
    if b(a, 0):
        print('...')
```

Comment: Same could be done with a lambda function. But your solution is way more clear.

Answer (score 3):

[BrokenBenchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17769815/brokenbenchmark) is right, passing a function is the way to achieve this. I wanted to explain a bit of what's happening under the hood.

Since this is passing a function as an argument (Side note: this means python functions are [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)), there are two ways we can achieve this: passing a function or a lambda (an inline function). Below are two examples of both.

```py
def b_func(x, y):
    return x >= y

b_lambda = lambda x, y: x >= y

a = int(input('number between 0 and 5'))
def fun1(a, b):
    if b(a, 0):
        print('...')
    
fun1(a, b_func)
fun1(a, b_lambda)
```